# google autocomplete not working in framework7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins, html-framework-7

i am trying to add google autocomplete for location suggesion in my framework7 based mobile application.I  gave  search text box within 
 google location suggestion is not working.After removing the class="page cached" it was working.i got location suggesion by using google autocomplete.why this happen?How to give google location suggesion in framework7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution. This is becuase of conflict with fast click.
The solution is to remove fast click

way 1:Remove entire fastclick from app
`var myApp = new Framework7({
      material: true,
   materialPageLoadDelay: 250,
   materialRipple: true,
   fastclick:false,
});`

way 2:remove fastclick only for goole suggestion area`$(document).on({
    'DOMNodeInserted': function() {
        $('.pac-item, .pac-item span', this).addClass('no-fastclick');
    }
}, '.pac-container');`
I prefer the second one sice fastclick is removed from only suggestion area.